# Data format returned by method for select element with data url in JQGrid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

What is the JSON data format returned to select element with the dataUrl option?

Here is the script to parameter the select option

```
{
    name: 'client',
    index: 'client',
    jsonmap: 'projetID.clientID.nom',
    editable: true,
    edittype: "select",
    width: 110,
    editoptions: {
        datatype: "json",
        dataUrl:'http://localhost:8080/GestionCra/clientsRest/listJsonSelect',
        dataEvents: [
            { 
                type: 'change',
                fn: function(e) {
                    var thisval = $(e.target).val();
                    $.get('http://localhost:8080/GestionCra/projetsRest/listJsonSelect?id='+thisval, function(data) {
                      var res = $(data).html();
                      $("#projet").html(res);
                    }); // end get
                }//end func
            } // end type
        ] // dataevents
    }, // edit option 
    search: true,
    stype: 'text'
}
```

Here is the method I'm using to fill select element with data 
return a string wit format: id: value; id: value...

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/listJsonSelect"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String listJsonSelect() {
    List<Client> listC=service.listClients();
    String clients="";
    for (Client client : listC) {
        clients+=client.getId()+":"+client.getNom()+";";
    }
    if(clients.length()>2)
        clients=clients.substring(0,clients.length()-1);
    return clients;
}
```

The execution gives this jquery error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 1:client 1;2:client 2;3:client 3;4:dfsdf;5:sdfsdf;6:sdfsdf;7:sdfsd;8:sdfsd;9:sdfsd;10:fsdf;11:sdfsdf

Answer (score 0):

Fixall.Site answer

According to the jqgrid documentation, your problem is that the dataUrl needs to return HTML containing the select element, not JSON:
The editoptions dataUrl parameter is valid only for element of edittype:select. The dataUrl parameter represent the url from where the html select element should be get.
When this option is set, the element will be filled with values from the AJAX request. The data should be a valid HTML select element with the desired options - something like:

```
<select>
<option value='1'>One</option>
<option value='2'>Two</option>
...
</select>
```

So the easiest solution is for you to just return HTML.
That said, I do not like the idea of returning UI elements directly. Another option is to use the buildselect function to construct the select element for you:
This option is relevant only if the dataUrl parameter is set. When the server response can not build the select element, you can use your own function to build the select. The function should return a string containing the select and options value(s) as described in dataUrl option. Parameter passed to this function is the server response
This answer provides an example of how to use buildselect.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code in the controller.

```
    $datos= $this->findAll( $criteria );
    $data="<select>";

    foreach ($datos as $value){
        $data .="<option value='".$value->datoValidoId."'>".$value->datovalido."</option>";
    }
    $data .="</select>";

    return $data;
```